# WebClient retrieving NULL as response body

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am invoking to a service with the following code:

```
WebClient.create().get()
                .uri("http://www.somehost.es/api/products/1319/?ws_key=DC63ZTBVVQLN9MHQPQ9UMTL2DSW55C63")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .doOnSuccess(System.out::println)
                .block();
```

And NULL is printed.
But when I copy that URL and paste it directly int Chrome, or into Postman, the body (which is XML) is correctly returned.

Why would WebClient return null instead?

Comment: Same problem, any takers on this? Spring Boot 2.3.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

I found a reason and that the URI is encoded by default:

https://www.baeldung.com/webflux-webclient-parameters#encoding-mode

this worked for me

Comment: did not woked for me, any other solution?